# What is the correct syntax for !:1- in csh

Tags: shell, csh

Im creating an alias like this in my cshrc file but I can't get it to work properly

```
alias fxg "find . -type f -name \!:1'*' | xargs grep \!:2-"
```

From what I understand!:2- should give me the arguments from the second to the last.

```
alias fxg "find . -type f -name \!:1'*' | xargs grep \!:2"
```

This row works as expected its just the all var-arg thing command that is not working.
Dose any one know how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use !2*:

```
% alias sec 'echo $\!2*'
% sec 1 2 3
```

Please [do not use csh](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt) if at all possible (no functions, ad-hoc unpredictable parser, broken I/O redirection -- see the link); it is a horrible shell that will give you nothing but problems in the future (and you will do your part in keeping this unworthy shell alive).